# Loop variable lifetime

Tags: c#, loops, variables, delegates, lifetime

Why does this example gives me ten times 10?

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        delegate void Printer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Printer> printers = new List<Printer>();

            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(i); });
            }
            foreach (var printer in printers)
            {
                printer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to throw an exception because `i` don't exist outside the loop.
I read a question on this forum with a similar topic and they mentioned how the *scope* and *lifetime* of the variable differ, but I'm still not sure what does that exactly mean.
Does `i` hold some kind of reference count and wait for it to become 0?

Comment: It's called a *captured variable*. Notice what happens if you do `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { var j = i; printers.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(j)); }`

Comment: IL doesn't support "captured variables" or "lambda methods". These C# features are implemented in the C# compiler by defining extra types. Reading the output of a C# decompiler will show you how it actually works, and may help you understand why. eg https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5nJQDMmMmcA7MujegN7W1PACmANiwOYCGALi5mzoACgCcAlgDt+ogBQBKfEiZMsANkHoAstymysqANoBddN1GcAzvMYr6tu7QAy4y7wA8YqTIB86AA4S0iyilugAvOiSLADu6C5unkG+CkoOjujpjgBmAPai6LLe6OIR6Ki4Jeju6HAVJWBgNsoZtAwtrSqB3iGWAHQAgsDAsqwcPPz05ACcRYroAL6KWXYLKyp5oizcAMYAFoUAbuYBySElkqc9oc2dNO13XWdyyx2ta29MH19AA===